# Can a iPhone discover Android Phones using Bluetooth or BLE?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I know that I can't connect an iOS Device with another Android device. I want to build an app using CoreBluetooth. I've heard that BLE can scan nearby to get other devices' names or to connect with them. To test this I downloaded several apps from the AppStore. I have an Android phone and an old iPhone 6, but all apps cannot see them. I thought that this is possible with BLE or did I miss something?

Comment: With BLE you need one device to be in the Peripheral Role and the other to be in the Central Role. I believe that iOS doesn't allow its phones to be in the Peripheral Role. As a test you could use the Android [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral) and then a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool (e.g. [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) ) on iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean to just detect a presence of another phone - I'm not sure.

If you mean to communicate between applications - yes, with BLE it's possible, both ways:

- iOS app as Central + Android app as Peripheral
- Android app as Central + iOS app as Peripheral

It's a good idea to have a quick check with already existing apps, as @ukBaz suggested in comment.

Also check example apps (source code) here: https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection - iOS, Android, all apps compatible with each other, read/write/notify.

Comment: Yeah, I already checked this with existing apps. My iPhone 6 is not showing up for any reason and with the android, it works on some apps but not on all. In Germany, we have a Corona-Warn-App that detects if an infected person was nearby. There are using BLE too. I want to build something similar.